# Google Play device compatibility

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the Play Store that is not using any features.  It has a minimum SDK and target SDK of 14, but besides that, only uses permissions and not features.  For some reason, Google Play is marking this application as not compatible with the Spice MI-530.

edit: Online, it looks like the MI-530 launched with API 14 but is upgradable to API 16.

Any ideas why that might be?  Is there somewhere that I can look and find a list of what data points Google uses to determine device compatibility for specific devices?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

The only other thing I can think of is that maybe declaring this intent filter might be the problem?

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.calendar.action.HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Double check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions Some permissions imply hardware features and if that particular device is missing a hardware feature and one of your permissions requires it, it will show as unsupported.